# Why is rs.next() not working properly?

Tags: java, mysql, oop

EDIT: SOLVED! Thanks guys! :D

Even if I type with the right credentials I still get the error showMessageDialog..
I believe that rs.next() will return a value higher than 0 then it has to confim if the user's credentials will match with the ones in the users_table but I'm always
getting the error message as if the credentials were mismatched.

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class System extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    // variables needed for db connection
    Connection conn;
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;
    String sql;
    String user;
    char[] pass;
    //for table row count
    int ctr = 0;
    //temporary variables needed in retrieving and inserting records  in our db
    int user_id;
    String username;
    String password;

    public System() {
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        dbConnect();
    }

    public void dbConnect() {
        conn = null;
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/item_db";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String userName = "root";
        String password = "";
        try {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);

            stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            sql = "Select * from users_table";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);//rs - will hold the records from the databa sql = "Select * from item_table";se

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void login() {

        try {
            if (user != null && pass != null) {
                sql = "Select * from users_table Where username='" + user + "' and password='" + pass + "'";
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

                rs.next();
                if ((user.equals(username)) && (pass.equals(password))) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are now logon!");
                } 
                else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "damn!", "alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException err) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, err.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPasswordField1 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Calibri", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Username:");

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Calibri", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Password:");

        jButton1.setText("Login");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Cancel");

        jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/login.png"))); // NOI18N

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(46, 46, 46)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(82, 82, 82)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField1)
                                    .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 134, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(51, 51, 51)
                                .addComponent(jButton1)
                                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                                .addComponent(jButton2)))))
                .addContainerGap(52, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addGap(29, 29, 29))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        //str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Enter id number: ");
        user = jTextField1.getText();
        pass = jPasswordField1.getPassword();
        login();
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(System.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(System.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(System.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(System.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new System().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Which of the dialogs is shown? If it is the one in the catch, which is the message?

Comment: you call `rs.next()` without checking the value at all! Also, you should use `PreparedStatement` or prepare yourself to meet [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: You've provided nearly *200* lines of code, the vast majority of which are going to be irrelevant. If you'd cut this down to a short but complete console application demonstrating the problem (and *only* the problem) I suspect it could be about 30 lines, if that.

Comment: Replace `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());` by `e.printStackTrace()`, and paste the complete stack trace here. Error messages are intended to be read: they're used to diagnose the problem.

Comment: And, BTW, http://sscce.org

Comment: (Oh, and you're inviting a SQL injection attack with the way you're executing your SQL, by the way. Use a prepared statement and set parameters.)

Comment: @SJuan76 I'm getting  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "damn!", "alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);  as if my credentials are wrong. JonSkeet  I don't know how to use prepared statement >.<

Answer (score 1):

You're not checking the return value from rs.next()

try:

```
            if (rs.next()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are now logon!");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "damn!", "alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
            }
```

see:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29

Comment: still getting JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "damn!", "alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); even correct credentials

Answer (score 1):

You define, but never assign a value to:

```
String username;
String password;
```

To get this check to work.

```
 if ((user.equals(username)) && (pass.equals(password))) {
```

You should before set the values for `username` and `password`

```
 this.username = rs.getString("username");
 this.password = rs.getString("password");
```

Anyway it is not needed. As these both values are in you `WHERE` clause, if you get any result at all it means that you got a hit, so you could just change the `if` to

```
 if (rs.next()) {
```

NOTE: You have to delete the previous `rs.next()` (you will get only one row for the query).

That said, a couple of hints:

1) Don't store unencrypted passwords. Store a hashed version (MD-5, SHA-1). If it is important, use a salt. That way, somebody that can read the table won't be able to guess the passwords. First you can test with unenctrypted table, when it works add encryption.

2) As someone else said, you are better off with `PreparedStatement`.

3) Unless you are using it often, don't make the connection an instance variable. Make it a local variable of the method that uses it. And `close()` it properly. That way you will not be hogging your server resources.

Comment: Can't make the password a string or else I wouldn't be able to use jPasswordField :|

Comment: You get a char[] from it, converting it to String is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You call rs.next in a vacuum.  You don't test the result or use the result set data.

Answer (score -1):

I think your code should be something like,

```
rs.next();
            if ((user.equals(rs.getString("username"))) && (pass.equals(rs.getString("password")))) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are now logon!");
            }
```

Comment: that `if` will always be `true`. Look at his SQL statement.

Comment: @jlordo - I respectfully disagree.  It will be true only of those username and password are in the database.  If no results are returned by the query, then this result of "if" condition will return false.

Comment: If they exist in the database, `rs.next()` will be `true` (provided he fixes his statement, because `pass` is a `char[]` and he can't use `+` to insert it into his string) **and** your `if` will be `true`. If they don't exist in the database, then `rs.next()` will be false and your `if` also. So it's better to use `if (rs.next())` and get rid of the `if` in your code.

Comment: I agree with using `if (rs.next())`.  Basically my point was that he was not even using the result to make the decision on whether the user is logged in or not.  The code is comparing two predefined strings.

Comment: I tried this: if (rs != null) {
                    if ((user.equals(rs.getString("username"))) && (pass.equals(rs.getString("password")))) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are now logon!");
                    } 
                    else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "damn!", "alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
                    }
                }  but I get "illegal operation on empty result set"

Comment: @Slowcoder: I understand your intentions. If you look close, you'll see that what you are doing (comparing the predefined one, with the one returned by the database) will always be `true`, because the database will only return rows, where exactly this condition is met. This is because the statement is `"Select * from users_table Where username='" + user + "' and password='" + pass + "'";`

Comment: @jlordo - But again it will not return true always.  It will be true for the successful login but it will throw "illegal operation on empty result set" error when the login is faile (Thanks Gian7 for testing it).  jlordo, Gian7 - I agree with both of you that what I suggested was a bad practice.  Thanks for waking me up though.

Comment: @Slowcoder: **YES**, that's why I said you should **replace** your `if` with `if (rs.next())` bacause if `rs` is empty it will fail (and `rs.next()` will be `false`) and if `rs` is not empty, your string comparison will **always** be `true`.

Comment: @jlordo - I think the number comments here is more than the number of answers :).  I totally agree with you on replacing the `if` condition with `if (rs.next()).  Good learning for me too. Thanks.